# Get cart info REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I need to get cart id using the following api 
http://localhost/rest/V1/carts/mine
but when I run that api using the following code

```
   $headers = array("Content-Type: application/json",
       'Authorization: Bearer token'
   );
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'/rest/V1/carts/mine');
   //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

I get the following error

```
 [message] => %fieldName is a required field.
[parameters] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fieldName] => customerId
    )
```

although I know that that request sent with empty body

Comment: make sure your are passing correct token, as per your question its not correct token.

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar token is correct. I'm generating it via this api http://localhost/project/rest/V1/integration/customer/token

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get customer token by following code

```
$baseUrl = 'http://localhost/proj2/';
        $token_url = $baseUrl.'index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token';
        $ch = curl_init($token_url);


        $data['username'] = 'customer_username';
        $data['password'] = 'customer_password';

        ////////////////  getting admin token from api
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Length: " . strlen(json_encode($data))));


        $token = curl_exec($ch);

        $customer_token = (json_decode($token));
```

Then pass token in your code after bearer. 
And after your code write

```
$customer_info = curl_exec($ch);
$customer_array = json_decode($customer_info);
```

Comment: I did so and get same error

Comment: have you added curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");  after curl_init ?

Comment: also add your new code